# Rails, Heroku and Activestorage - how to restore a broken link to a file on AWS S3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, heroku, rails-activestorage

I have an small app deployed on Heroku that stores a bunch of CSV's in an S3 bucket configured via Activestorage.

I recently upgraded the Rails version of the app, and didn't notice that it had reset production.rb so it again read

```
config.active_storage.service = :local
```

I've changed it back to :amazon, and anything newly created by the app is getting saved and linked to properly as before, but links to ActiveStorage records from pre-migration are now pointed at addresses on the local domain, which then 404.

Is there any way to restore the link to the files that are still sitting on AWS instead?

Comment: what does it return when do you something like `MyModel.first.image.url` for both `:local` and `config.active_storage.service = :amazon`?

Comment: Cheers for your response!

On one of the older one's, I get

`ArgumentError (Cannot generate URL for Test_File.zip using Disk service, please set ActiveStorage::Current.url_options.)`

If I do that on a model created after the upgrade, I do get the bucketter URL successfully.

Comment: so switching back to `:amazon` works now?

Comment: If I'm not wrong, it should throw a different error for, when storage is set to `:amazon`